# angular2 routing component files loads on startup

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am making an angular2 application but all the routing component loads at start up. I have read about the lazy loading of route by converting them to feature and having separate ngmodule. but how can we do it without have a separate ngmodule and how can I prevent the route component to load on startup.

Comment: By moving the component to a lazy loaded module and configure the router to lazy load it. Why would you want to do it without `NgModule` when `NgModule` was introduce for exactly this purpose?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So if I have 20 Screens and I want to have all of them loaded async. then I would have to define 20 NgModules ? Or should I define one more NgModule and define their routes in that NgModule. but would it not load all child of that NgModules when i load any screen from that module ??

Comment: What you want to load in once request needs to be one `NgModule`. If you want to lazy load all lazy loaded components at once, then you can pack them all into one `NgModule`. If you don't want this and lazy load components one-by-one, you need an `NgModule` for each.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a read the following introduction to the new router and it also explains how to achieve lazy loading using the new @NgModule feature. Going forwarding you need to use the @NgModule as this is the approach Angular team took since the release candidate number 5.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for lazy loading concept with the angular 2 then you just have to make some changes in your routes ... You have to make them load only when they are required ...

```
new AsyncRoute({
path: '/login',
loader: () => System.import('./dist/login.component').then(m => m.loginComponent),
name: 'Login'   })
```

just don't forget to import asyncroute.. that's how concept of lazy loading works with angular 2 :)

further you can check this out at https://www.xplatform.rocks/2016/02/09/angular2-quicky-async-routes/

i hope this is what u were looking for :)

Comment: for latest RC5 we have ngmodule for lazy loading